# Setting attributes of Range Slider using knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, knockout.js, jquery-ui-slider

I am new to knockout.js and wish to ask a simple small question.

I have the following simple JQuery mobile range slider that works fine:

```
<input min=1 max=50 value=3 type="range"  data-highlight="true">
```

I now wish to change max and value attributes dynamically. Here is my HTML:

```
<input data-bind="min: 1, max: MaxPage, value: CurrPage" type="range"  data-highlight="true">
```

And this is my JavaScript:

```
var x1 = 8;
var x2 = 40;

function ViewModel () {
    this.CurrPage = ko.observable(x1);
    this.MaxPage = ko.observable(x2);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

But that's not working. Here is the full [jsfiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/X82aC/479/)
Can someone please advise what I am doing wrong.

Also what do I need to do, if I wish to update x1 with the change in slider's value?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `max` and `min` bindings, which Knockout doesn't have, it should be [attr](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html):

```
<input data-bind="attr: {min: 1, max: MaxPage}, value: CurrPage" type="range" data-highlight="true">
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X82aC/490/).

Also, your fiddle didn't work until I set delayed everything to `domReady`.

To update `x1`, subscribe for `this.CurrPage` changes inside `ViewModel`:

```
this.CurrPage.subscribe(function (value) {
    x1 = value;
});
```

You can read about subscribing in [observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) docs.

**Update:** In order to change `x1`, call `CurrPage(value)`, `changeCurrent` function below does exactly that:

```
var x1 = 8,
    x2 = 40;

function ViewModel () {
    this.CurrPage = ko.observable(x1);
    this.MaxPage = ko.observable(x2);

    this.CurrPage.subscribe(function (value) {
        x1 = value;
    });

    this.changeCurrent = function () {
        this.CurrPage(13);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```
<button data-bind="click: changeCurrent">Change current</button>
```

I strongly advise you to read Knockout documentation and working throught interactive tutorial.

**Update 2:** To call `changeCurrent` directly from the code, you need to have ViewModel instance reference:

```
function ViewModel() {
    ...
};

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

vm.CurrPage(13);
```

Comment: I am trying to change the value of x1 in another function to see the reverse impact on slider, but unable to do so. Please check this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X82aC/489/

Comment: You should change observables to impact x's.

Comment: how? Any example please? I am totally new to this stuff. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, one more question. How do I call changeCurrent directly from the code instead of binding it with a button click? ViewModel().changeCurrent() doesn't work. Apologies for too much basic level questions.

Comment: thanks. However vm.CurrPage(13) doesn't work. Instead I called vm.changeCurrent(); which was working and appears to be updating the CurrPage value also. However, it does't show any impact on the slider to which the values are bound. Any idea?

Comment: I think this example is closer to the issue that I am facing: http://jsfiddle.net/X82aC/494/